# Undefined methods and instance variables

Tags: ruby, methods, instance-variables

I am trying to build a very very simple computer module that allows you to create files, view them, and edit them.  I am having trouble with undefined methods and the exact nature of instance variables. I will get to those later.  You can tl;dr and just go to the bolded areas.

```
class Computer
@@users = Hash.new
def initialize(username, password)
    @username = username
    @password = password
    @files = Hash.new
    @files["Groceries.txt"] = "10:20"
    @files["Blane.txt"] = "10:30"
    @@users[username] = password
end
def create(filename)
    time = Time.now
    @files[filename] = time
    puts "A new file, #{filename}, was created at #{time}"
end
def Computer.get_users
    return @@users
end
end
```

So I am just defining my class variable "Computer" here.

```
puts "You need to login!"
puts "Username?"
userName = gets.chomp.downcase
puts "Password?"
passWord = gets.chomp
my_computer = Computer.new(userName, passWord)
puts "You logged in with Username: #{userName}"
puts "and Password: #{passWord}" 
puts "What would you like to do?"
puts "-- Create a file (type create)"
puts "-- Change a file (type change)"
puts "-- View a file (type view)"
puts "-- Delete a file (type delete)"
answer = gets.chomp.downcase
case answer
when "create" 
    puts "What is the name of the file?"
    @create = gets.chomp.capitalize
    if @files[@create].nil?
    my_computer.create(@create)
    else
        puts "That file already exists!"
    end
when "change"
    puts "What is the name of the file you want to change?"
    @files.each do |x, y|
        puts "#{x}: #{y}"
    end
    @change = gets.chomp.capitalize
end
```

**Now when I get the error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" which is referring to the line**

```
if @files[@create].nil?
```

which is just checking if the new file is already in it.  I don't know if this is a problem with where I am defining the variables, or if it is that they are instance variables, or what the problem is.  Furthermore if I add the line:

```
my_computer.initialize(userName, passWord)
```

**I get the following error:
private method `initialize' called for #**

My final problem is that when I try and print out the filenames that exist already with the following code

```
@files.each do |x, y|
        puts "#{x}: #{y}"
    end
```

**I get the following error:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass**

I thought that the .each method was universal, but now it seems I have to define it in my class?

Sorry for the wall of text, but I'm very new to ruby and this is my first programming language, so I am trying to figure out the nuances of the language.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I like how I'm a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if @files[@create].nil?
```

and

```
@files.each do |x, y|
    puts "#{x}: #{y}"
end
```

This code is placed outside of the `Computer` class definition. And since `@files` is a class instance variable (it's defined inside the `Class Computer... end` block), it's only accessible within the class itself. It's NOT accessible outside of it.

```
my_computer.initialize(userName, passWord)
```

You cannot directly call the `initialize` method. Alternatively, this method is automatically called when you call a `new` method. So your code:

```
my_computer = Computer.new(userName, passWord)
```

Automatically calls `initialize` on `my_computer`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was curious about the initialize method. Is initialize a special type of method that automatically activates, or is because when I created my_computer and specified two parameters it defaulted to initialize because it takes two parameters?

So for the files, if it is a class variable, should I make it an instance variable? Global? Or some other one?

Comment: @user3688362 `initialize` is actually automatically invoked within the `new` method, that explains why you are expected to pass the same number of parameters to `new` as you've declared that `initialize` takes. Still, don't even think to define a `new` method :)

Comment: Also I thought that the @variable was an instance variable and @@variable was a class variable.

Comment: Also if initialize is automatically invoked, is the create method also invoked automatically? Or would it be automatically invoked if I defined a new variable with one parameter, as opposed to two?

Comment: @AndrewWeatherly `@variable` is a class instance variable, That means there's a `@files` variable within every instance of `Computer`. However, `@@variable` is a class variable, that means there's a single `@@variable` that's shared among all instances of `Computer`. Still, both of them are only accessible within the class definition.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. So if I want to display the @files hash, should I make it a global variable instead?

Comment: @AndrewWeatherly Regarding `initialize` and `create`. The method that's named `initialize` is considered *special* by Ruby and only it is automatically invoke whenever a new instance is created. All other methods, including your `create` method, are just ordinary methods that are invoked only when you invoke them.

Comment: @AndrewWeatherly No. You should define a `get_files` method that just `return @files`. You need to read more about getters and setters, I advice you to go read a good ruby tutorial. Maybe [Codecademy's Ruby track](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/ruby) is the best one.

Comment: I'm actually doing the codeacademy tutorial. This is one of the projects, and I'm just expanding it a LOT, to test what I know. Thanks for the help!